# Anyone knows what's the name of this component?

Tags: car, bmw

**Car**

BMW N13B16 316i

Anyone knows what's the name of this component which connected 3 pipes? that part seems leaking engine oil, I'd like to replace it but don't know what's the name.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the car in question? Seeing BMW in the tags does very little to help us tell you what the part is ... just a guess otherwise.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thanks, I have figured out the name is Electronic Auxiliary Pump which used to cool the turbo after engine off.